# How to install Google Sandbox2 on linux

Tags: sandbox

Can someone guide me through a set procedure on installing and using google sandbox2 API on Ubuntu 16.04 .
The documentation on google developers is not helping me.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://developers.google.com/sandboxed-api/docs/overview) is not helpful?

Answer (score 0):

One of the developers of Sandboxed API here. Can you be a bit more specific on what you tried and what you would like to know?

As for your setup, we recommend you use a newer version of Ubuntu, such as 19.04 or a recent Debian.

Finally, if you want to add sandboxing to an existing open source project, you may be eligible for the Patch Rewards Program, if upstream accepts your changes (Google "Patch Rewards Program").